# php - Laravel : how to Load Ajax data after selected changes from dropdown?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to load some ajax data after selected a value from dropdown in textbox.

**Eg:** After selecting a teacher from dropdown, teachers remaining credit  and credit_taken value should be load. How do I do it with ajax?

**NB:** Here teacher value has selected from another dropdown selecting in Ajax

```
<script>
      $('#teacher').on('change',function(e){            
           var teach_id = $('#teacher option:selected').attr('value');

             var info=$.get("{{url('ajax-teach')}}",{teach_id:teach_id});
               info.done(function(data){     
                  $.each(data,function(index,subcatObj){

               /// Here will  be the loaded code   ///

                    });                    
        });

        info.fail(function(){
          alert('ok');
        });
       });
    </script>
```

Here is **my controller:**

```
Route::get('ajax-teach',function(Request $request){ 
        $teach_id = $request::input(['teach_id']);          
        $teachers=\App\Teacher::where('teacher_id','=',$teach_id)->get();
        return Response::json($teachers);   
});
```

Here is the **view Page:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Teacher</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" required name="teacher_id" id="teacher" >
    <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</div> 


<div class="form-group">
  <label>Credit to be Taken</label>         
  <input type="text" name="credit_taken" id="credit_taken" class="form-control" required placeholder="Credit to be Taken">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Remaining Credit</label>         
  <input type="text" name="remaining_credit" class="form-control" required placeholder="Remaining Credit">
</div>
```

Comment: do you have a multiple option select?,how does the teacher json look like?

Comment: See Here teacher comes from the department dropdown. When a user select a particular  department, teachers list will be shown in next dropdown who are belongs to that department. When I select a teacher, I have to shown that particular teacher data in that textbox which I have mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

In your routes (`routes/web.php`)

```
Route::get( '/ajaxteach', array(
    'as' => 'ajaxteach',
    'uses' => 'TeachController@get_teach'
) );
```

In your controller (`app/Http/Controllers/TeachController.php`)

```
class TeachController extends Controller
{
    public function get_teach(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        $teach_id = $request->get('teach_id');          
        $teachers=\App\Teacher::where('teacher_id','=',$dept_id)->get();
        return response()->json(['response' => $teachers]);
    }
}
```

Then in your AJAX script you can use at least one of the following ways

1. use absolute url in javascript code

   ```
   var base_url = 'http://localhost/laravel'
   $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url : base_url+"/ajaxteach",
          data : dataString,
          success : function(data){
                 console.log(data);
          }
   ```
2. use `url()` with route

   ```
   $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url : "{{url('ajaxteach')}}",
          data : dataString,
          success : function(data){
                 console.log(data);
          }
   ```

Comment: you forgot to echo the url {{}}

Comment: How will it send the data to my credit_taken text box or remaining_credit text box in view page?
Just asking I am new to Ajax!

Comment: Randeep Singh , you can use :      $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : "{{url('ajaxteach')}}",
                data : dataString,
                success : function(data){
                   var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data);    $('#credit_taken').val(json_obj.credit_taken) ; $('#remaining_credit').val(json_obj.remaining_credit) ; 
                }

Comment: What will be the changed in view page? 
How to catch the data in view?
for credit_taken or remaining_credit . etc.